# Enviar datos de una tabla dentro de un modal en JSP

Tags: javascript, html5, jsp, modal

Buen día,

Estoy tratando de enviar datos de una tabla que consulta datos de una base de datos en SQL, mediante una ventana modal que al dar clic sobre el botón este me envié los datos hacia unos textimput, he estado intentado de varias formas mediante investigación en internet pero no he logrado hacerlo.

En el código HTML agrego un botón el cual abre el modal que carga los datos de de la base de datos,

Código HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal " name="f_Agregar" id="FI_Agregar" action="Pedidos.jsp" method="POST">    
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn3">Add Cliente</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Codigo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="f_Ccode">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="fcname" name="f_cname">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Código del modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Cliente</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">

                    <table id="table" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Seleccionar</th>
                                <th>Codigo</th>
                                <th>DNI</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Direccion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <%
                                //listar los productos que existen en la base de datos
                                try {
                                    db.Connect();
                                    db.Syn = db.GetCmd().prepareStatement("{call sp_sCliente}");
                                    db.Syn.executeQuery();
                                    ResultSet rs = db.Syn.getResultSet();
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                        String v_ID = rs.getString(1);
                                        String v_codigo = rs.getString(2);
                                        String v_DNI = rs.getString(3);
                                        String Nombre = rs.getString(4);
                                        String Direccion = rs.getString(5);


                            %>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" id="<%=v_ID%>">Ver</button> 
                                </td>

                                <td class="invoice-amt"><%=v_codigo%></td>
                                <td class="cheque-amt"><%=v_DNI%></td>
                                <td id="Cname"><%=Nombre%></td>
                                <td id="Cdir"><%=Direccion%></td>
                            </tr>
                            <%
                                    }
                                    db.Disconnect();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            %>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>




<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addProduct").click(function () {
            $("#myModaladdproduct").modal({backdrop: "static"});
        });

    });
</script>
```

Si me pueden indicar que hacer se los agradecería mucho ya que he intentado de muchas maneras y ninguna me ha funcionado para lo que necesito.